# How to make windows form application run as different user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, winforms, active-directory

I'm creating a simple file copy program on our intranet to allow users to copy a file to a specific network folder which they do not have access too.  I plan to use the the "CopyFile" function from "My.Computer.FileSystem" Namespace since it will uses Windows built-in file copy dialog and progress bar.  I assume the user needs to have authentication to this folder.  I would like to know if I can have the program run as an authenticated user of this network folder for the file copy to work?  Thank you.

Comment: Write a service (with enough privileges) that copies the file to the destination folder when requested.

Comment: search for impersonation

Comment: What about WindowsIdentity.Impersonate?  Will this accomplish the task without a separate service (or process as mentioned below)? [edit] Thanks Vlad, you posted right before I commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start a separate process for that. You can use Process.Start(...)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxf2saat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

**EDIT**:

based on your comment I did also a quick check up on impersonation. This from Matt Johnson post seems promising!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7250145/2243584

Comment: What about security? Will you put the username/password into the code?

Comment: I guess that is actually what he/she wants, as mentionend "which they do not have access to"

Comment: So the application I would have the user start from their desktop is actually the process I write, which will then run my simple program with the proper credentials?

Comment: @merlot that is how I understood you. The user starts a program, which then itself starts your application with different credentials. Yes.

Comment: @toATwork - thanks, I'll look into seperate process vs. impersonation

Comment: I found an issue with Impersonation.  When I use the OpenFileDialog, it shows the mapped network drives as letters only, even though you can browse them.  When you try to copy a file it says "path not found".  I you go to the driver on the server under network, it works fine.

Comment: @merlot are you doing the copy also in the impersonation part? It looks like for the user which is doing the copy that network path is not available

Comment: @toATwork Yes, I copy in the impersonation.  I tried using the OpenFileDialog outside of impersonation and get the same issue.  I also tried running a process instead of impersonation - same issue.  I believe the issue lies in the OpenFileDialog path.  I decided I will alter the path to remove the shortcut drive letter and insert the server name into the path - this should work fine.  My only issue is if someone maps a drive I don't know about.  Since I'm also the network admin, I assign which drive letter maps to which folder on each server.

Comment: @merlot the OpenFileDialog needs to be in impersonation as well, because the mapped network drives might be different otherwise. I also agree that the UNC path is the way to go.